# Azure virtual machine used as IIS server

Tags: azure, zumero

I need server to setup Zumero Sync on it , I already used azure free trail now I need to upgrade but don't know if I need only to buy VM or Cloud service with it , it's not clear how to use the VM , is it like VPS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to [Pay as you go subscription](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/offers/ms-azr-0003p/) model which means you have to pay for what you use so in your case you have to pay for the VM and storage for storing the VHD of the VM. Cloud Service is basically a shell under which you deploy a VM so you don't need to pay for it.You can minimize the cost by shutting down the VM when not in use.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Azure Resource Managed (announced recently by MS: [IaaS Just Got Easier](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/29/iaas-just-got-easier-again/)) the portal (and PowerShell) forces you to create a Cloud Service otherwise there's no way for you to assign an external DNS to connect to your VM.  You won't need to do anything with it other than set it up if you're using a VM, but it will need to be there.

If you're not using a VM, your Cloud Service is the container for your deployment, which means you don't need to worry about maintaining IIS or Windows (which your app still runs on in the background).